# filling space in value according to length of field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have sql query as:

```
select UJIdentifyer,RecordIdentity,Location,DeptTime,BayNumber,TimingPointIndicatior,
FareStageIndicatior  
from QO where UJIdentifyer='139013'
```

In this query's result, every column's value length is fixed.

Eg. Its mandatory to have `Location` column with 12 character length.

If it is of 11 then one space should get filled in it, if 10 then 2 spaces.

For this i written :

```
 select UJIdentifyer,case when len(RecordIdentity)=11 then RecordIdentity+''else when len(RecordIdentity)=10 then RecordIdentity+'  '....   from QO where UJIdentifyer='139013'
```

Like this i will have to write 10-12 cases for length matching.

Is there any way through which i can avoid repetition of those similar cases??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
  case when datalength(Location ) <12 
       then Location + replicate (' ' ,12-datalength(Location))
  END
```

Example:-

```
 Declare @var varchar(12) = 'SQL'

 Select datalength(@var) InitialLength, 
        case when datalength(@var) <12 
              then @var + replicate (' ' ,12-datalength(@var)) 
        END as PaddingExtraSpaces,
        Datalength(case when datalength(@var) <12 
                        then @var + replicate (' ' ,12-datalength(@var)) 
                  END ) FinalLength
```

Result

```
  IntialLength    PaddingExtraSpaces   FinalLength
     2               SQL                  12
```

Use `Datalength` to get the number of characters including `blanks`